# Error message of missing jr file when running Android Studio application on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-emulator, illegalstateexception

I am trying to run an app on my Android Studio IDE. The imported files for the app are made with an older gradle configuration, and that an older version of Android Studio (Android Studio 2.3.2) is being used. The emulator is a Nexus 6 with API 23. The emulator is working. However, every time I try to run the app, I get the error message:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: dx.jar is missing

It says that a "dx.jar file is missing", and  I also get a message in the "Messages Gradle Build" window that the "BUILD FAILED". Is there anything I can do to make the app run properly on the emulator? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this to your app `build.gradle` file

```
    defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```